# Azure Functions, Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, azure-functions

When using the [NuGet.Protocol](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Protocol) NuGet Package in Azure Functions, I get the following error: `System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly`.

```sh
[4/18/2020 8:51:43 AM] The 'Function1' function is in error: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
[4/18/2020 8:51:43 AM] Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.Protocol, Version=5.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.
[4/18/2020 8:51:43 AM] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Function1'. System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.Protocol, Version=5.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I confirmed that the `NuGet.Protocol.dll` file exists in the `bin` output.

[image]

Why can Azure Functions not find `NuGet.Protocol.dll`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is a [known-problem with Azure Functions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5894), introduced in [`Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` v3.0.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions), and still present today (v3.0.11).

To prevent Azure Functions from removing this library, add the following to your CSPROJ:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Here is an example of how I use it in my [GitTrends](https://gittrends.com) app:
https://github.com/brminnick/GitTrends/blob/22d748fc72452dcd39bb3866e30f339827ded3dd/GitTrends.Functions/GitTrends.Functions.csproj#L10

Comment: The solution for in-process Azure Functions continues to be undocumented. I wrote a blog post that might help at: https://bryanknox.github.io/2022/07/15/functionsskipcleanoutput-and-functionspreserveddependencies.html