# How to use System.Text.Json 7 in a in-process Azure function?

Tags: .net, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I've a nuget reference to `System.Text.Json 7.0.1` in a in-process Azure function, targeting
`.NET 6`  When starting the function locally I got a runtime error,

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51

What is the problem? Is it due to the fact that the function is running in-process?

Comment: Yes; likely due to it being an in-process func app. It'll try to remove redundant assemblies and since `System.Text.Json` is already part of the boilerplate it'll likely remove it causing the error. You could try adding the dependency in your `.csproj` using `FunctionsPreservedDependencies` to preserve it. Possibly also `System.Text.Encodings.Web` since the package has a dependency with it.

Comment: Thank you @NotFound. I found a another solution that seems to work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66084146/162003, What's the difference between using <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput> and FunctionPreservedDependencies?

Comment: `_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput` works over all assemblies. Using `FunctionPreservedDependencies` you narrow it down to particular assemblies, which is more efficient but requires extra tinkering with the exact assembly names to get it working.